# Remove specific character that repeats more than once, and leave only one

Tags: string, bash, posix

I've looked at answers of how to remove duplicate words for the last 20 minutes, trying to make them work for my use case, but that didn't work.

I have a small command that deletes special characters and transforms spaces into dashes,

```sh
echo "[[[h[el]lo - w{o}rld%^& -text" | tr -d '?$#@;:/\="<>%{}|^~[]&`' | tr ' ' '-'
```

and that produces the following output

```
hello---world--text
```

That runs perfectly, but I also want to add something else to that command, maybe another pipe, that removes the dashes that repeat

ex: I want it to transform, from the produced output, to:

```
hello-world-text
```

How can I do this in the most POSIX compliant way possible?

PS: Please tell me if there's a more efficient way to accomplish what I already made there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-s` flag for that:

```
echo "[[[h[el]lo - w{o}rld%^& -text" | tr -d '?$#@;:/\="<>%{}|^~[]&`' | tr -s ' ' '-'
```

---

```
-s, --squeeze-repeats
              replace each sequence of a repeated character that is listed in the  last
              specified SET, with a single occurrence of that character
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I remember looking through the help page, I don't know how I could've possibly skipped that

Answer (score 1):

For ***this*** particular case we can have `tr` delete everything ***except*** `-` and letters/digits (`[:alnum:]`)

```
$ echo "[[[h[el]lo - w{o}rld%^& -text" | tr -dc -- '-[:alnum:]'
hello-world-text

### or

$ tr -dc -- '-[:alnum:]' <<< "[[[h[el]lo - w{o}rld%^& -text"
hello-world-text
```

The key is the `-c` flag which says to take the complement (ie, *everything except*) of the given pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sed`:

```
$ echo "[[[h[el]lo - w{o}rld%^& -text" | sed -E 's/([^-[:alnum:]]*)//g'
hello-world-text
```